# function hover () has a great latency

Tags: python, function, hover

I need to make the emulation movement of the cursor, similar to the movement of the cursor controlled by a person, the function of hover () has a delay before the transition to the new kardinatu about 0.4s, which is very much to draw complex geometric shapes to do with the speed of a person is not possible, and it will be clear from that a robot. there are solutions to this problem?